# Issues customizing PFLoginViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I've subclassed `PFLoginViewController` and am doing my UI customizations in `viewWillAppear`. This seems to work fine for some buttons and fields.

Here is my login screen when the app first loads: http://cl.ly/image/2J0v3K313W3A

The following customizations all take hold:

```
self.logInView?.logInButton?.setTitle("LOGIN", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.logInView?.logInButton?.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.openSansSemiBoldFontOfSize(18)
self.logInView?.signUpButton?.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.openSansSemiBoldFontOfSize(18)
```

I also have the following customizations that don't take:

```
self.logInView?.signUpButton?.setTitle("SIGN UP", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.logInView?.logInButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 136/255, green: 192/255, blue: 87/255, alpha: 1)
self.logInView!.signUpButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 136/255, green: 192/255, blue: 87/255, alpha: 1)
```

Except...If I tap the 'Sign Up' button at the bottom, then dismiss the sign up view controller, when the login view controller re-appears, the 'sign up' is capitalized like it should be. But the button background hasn't changed.

http://cl.ly/image/0g0P1z0v1I1a

I just can't wrap my head around why some of the customizations work and some don't. The code is all in the same place. How can `setTitle` work for one button but not the other when the view fist appears?

Totally stumped.

** For disclosure, I have tried moving all my customization code to before presenting the login controller. It made zero difference.

Comment: So, the subclassing of this controller is fine, but more than likely this controler is feeding off of another file like a subclassed UIView called "PFLoginView" and if this is case then of course your modifications won't work.

Comment: and you're telling me that the "loadView" method in the PFLoginViewController doesn't show this: - (void)loadView {
    _logInView = [[PFLogInView alloc] initWithFields:_fields];
    [_logInView setPresentingViewController:self];
    self.view = _logInView;
}   You can't subclass a viewcontroller who's view is being fed by another subclass unless you first disconnect that view and use your own subclass view. if you subclass  a UIViewController, the parent class really shouldn't have a loadview method in the first place, a subclass uiviewcontroller should be a subclass by itself.

Comment: @Larcerax Thank you. I'm following Parse's own documentation for subclassing PFLoginViewController. https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views Section 3.1 shows changes being made to the logInView property as I've made them. I've moved the code to viewDidLoad to mimic the Parse docs more precisely. No change.

Comment: ahh yes, okay, I'm looking at this tutorial right now, all I can say about this tutorial is that it's terrible, it's going to make your job very difficult to subclass this as much as you want to given that they are using a hybrid of storyboards, nibs, and programmatic views WITHTOUT subclassing the programmatic views away from the view controller. this makes it nearly impossible for a beginner to wrap their head around what's going on. I don't have a better tutorial for you, but if you were to shift to Objctive-C then their Anypic demo is going to be much easier to swallow.

Comment: @Larcerax understood. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I used that when I first started @moz and loved it.

Comment: @moz put the code in 'viewDidAppear'

Answer (score 0):

The reason the background colors are not updation is that you have passed them as integer. And in the case of integer the result that they are getting will be equal to Zero.

```
self.logInView?.logInButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 136/255, green: 192/255, blue: 87/255, alpha: 1)
self.logInView!.signUpButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 136/255, green: 192/255, blue: 87/255, alpha: 1)
```

This code will be read by the compiler as

```
self.logInView?.logInButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
self.logInView!.signUpButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

To fix this issue you need to pass the values as doubles.
So try running the code as this

```
self.logInView?.logInButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 136.0/255.0, green: 192.0/255.0, blue: 87.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
self.logInView!.signUpButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 136.0/255.0, green: 192.0/255.0, blue: 87.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Sadly this did not have any impact.